# CKEditor and Bootstrap CSS specificity

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

So I am trying to add Bootstrap buttons to a CKEditor dialog. The CKEditor editor.css is overriding what makes a bootstrap button what it is.

What I am confused about is the specificity in Chrome seems to be wrong. But I'm sure it must be something else, Chrome couldn't be this wrong surely?

[image: CssSpecificity]

To quote the [Mozilla foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ') and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity.

and

> Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles, regardless of the specificity of the inherited rule.

As far as I can see .cke_reset_all *, is an inherited style and the .btn .btn-primary are directly targeted. So why is CKEditor winning with styles?

IE 11 behaves the same way too.

Comment: What is the hierarchy of your css styles in your `<head>`? The Bootstrap css file should go under the CKEditor css file.

Comment: Only if there was a conflict. I did start down this path because the (ck)Editor.css is loaded by JS when the CKEditor is initialised. But according to several posts I've read this should only matter when there is a conflict.

Comment: If you have no control of where to place the css files then my second attempt would be to get all the Bootstrap `.btn` classes and put it in your custom css file. Then mark all the `.btn` styles as `!important`.